# Error "First Element must contain the local name, Envelop" when consuming JMS messages

Tags: wso2, jms, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

While my listener runs it gives this error as soon as I run it. Unable to figure out what does it

```
2023-02-01 16:33:59,899] ERROR {JMSMessageReceiver} - Unknown error processing message org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found prov
```

Payload I am listening starts like below:

```xml
<prov><rowID>122</rowID><msisdn>110000171</msisdn>
```

Below is the settings of config in proxy service I am listening the msg from:

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">PROV.MAP.RT</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">ProvMapperRealtimeListener</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JMS Inbound Endpoint to listen to the queue, set the following property in the Inbound EP configs.

```xml
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
```

**Update**

In your Proxy configuration change the following property.

```xml
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
```

**Explanation**

When a message comes into WSO2 it would be converted to a processable format based on the Content-Type of the message. For this WSO2 uses message builders, the appropriate builder is selected based on the Content-Type. By default `text/plain` Content-Type is built with the SOAP message builder, hence it expects a proper SOAP message body. Since you have an XML instead it fails with the aforementioned error. Once you change the Content-Type to `application/xml` it would be built as an XML.

Comment: I am using proxy service and the properties set has been updated above please check

Comment: can you please help me with why application/xml and not text/xml

Comment: @WajihHaider I added some details take a look.

Comment: can you also help me understand that will all messages which can be listened by text/xml be listened by application/xml or they would be blocked ?

Comment: @WajihHaider yes you should be able to consume any valid XML.