# How to change the payload for first element local name envelope

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

Need help with how can we change following xml payload:

```
 <prov>
 <rowID>122</rowID>
 <msisdn>110000171</msisdn>
 <prov>
```

So we can have the following error resolved:

```
2023-02-01 16:33:59,899] ERROR {JMSMessageReceiver} - Unknown error processing message org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found prov
```

Any help would mean a lot.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Error "First Element must contain the local name, Envelop" when consuming JMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75311547/error-first-element-must-contain-the-local-name-envelop-when-consuming-jms-me)

Comment: No the solution given to cater it was to change configuration.. however now solution needed is that how to cater Payload without changing configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change configuration you have to change your message then.

```
 <Envelope>
  <Body>
    <prov>
      <rowID>122</rowID>
      <msisdn>110000171</msisdn>
    </prov>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

This format adheres to the standard structure of a SOAP message, which requires the first element to be Envelope and the data to be enclosed within the Body element.
By default text/plain Content-Type is built with the SOAP message builder, hence it expects a proper SOAP message body.